Theta old token and Theta Mainnet token
My Ethereum address shows me two versions of the Theta old token (with a different value) and Theta with the current market price.
Theta old token is only visible in Rabby wallet.
While Theta with the current Market Price is only visible when I scan with Etherscan.
What‘s strange is that I can‘t access Theta on the Theta Mainnet, and it doesn’t Show any information on the Theta Explorer.
Any ideas why I see the Theta old token only on Rabby wallet, Theta, supposedly, current token on Etherscan, but nothing on Theta Mainnet, not even the Explorer?
Thank you.

Hey MWohks, we only deal with questions about Bitcoin on this Stack Exchange. I’ve migrated your question to the Ethereum Stack Exchange, which might be able to provide more insights: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/167228
